# Error in Opening Report from Form

Tags: forms, report, ms-access-2013

I have a Form which will help me to filter out the records I want for my Report. The button will open the Report On Click.

[image: Form]

This is the code in the button:

```
Private Sub Open_OEE_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "OEE_Report", acViewReport, , , acWindowNormal

End Sub
```

I keep getting the error:

[image: RunTime Error 3071]

I also have placed the query in my report under the Record Source as:

```
SELECT * FROM 3_OEE WHERE ((([3_OEE].RecordID)=Forms![3_OEE_Report]!cboRecordID) And (([3_OEE].Date_Recorded)=DateValue(Forms![3_OEE_Report]!Date_Recorded)) And (([3_OEE].MC_No)=Forms![3_OEE_Report]!cboMCNo) And (([3_OEE].Product)=Forms![3_OEE_Report]!cboProduct));
```

**I want to search based on one criteria (text box or combo box) and not all four at once.**

Am I missing out something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked for help from another source.
[Answer to Question](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28992007/Run-Time-Error-3071.html)

Answer (score 0):

MS-Access does tend to go a bit overboard with the brackets. Make the report's Record Source a bit easier to read by trimming out the unnecessary ones. You also need to get your date criterion in the right format - Access always uses US formatting in SQL queries and needs `#` signs around the date:

```
SELECT * FROM 3_OEE 
    WHERE [3_OEE].RecordID = Forms![3_OEE_Report]!cboRecordID 
    And [3_OEE].Date_Recorded = Format(Forms![3_OEE_Report]!Date_Recorded, "\#mm/dd/yyyy\#")
    And [3_OEE].MC_No = Forms![3_OEE_Report]!cboMCNo 
    And [3_OEE].Product = Forms![3_OEE_Report]!cboProduct;
```

I would also suggest creating a named query for this and setting the report's Record Source to the named query. You can then test the query in isolation without having to run the report (but make sure the Form is open and the relevant controls are populated).